# DocuSign Envelope in status 'Created' which stores it in draft folder and when I click Send the envelope is not received by the recipient.

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

DocuSign Envelope in status 'Created' which stores it in draft folder. When I click 'Send',  envelope is not received by the recipient. It shows in 'Waiting for Others'. What does that mean? My Envelope request JSON is as below. After I get envelope Id I make a POST request to do embedded signing, I get the sender view url which opens in a new SalesForce Tab. When I click 'Send' it displays 'Success' message but the recipient does not get email.

```
{
    "status": "created",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": null,
                    "xPosition": null,
                    "width": "100",
                    "TabLabel": null,
                    "tabid": null,
                    "ScaleValue": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "RecipientId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "optional": "false",
                    "Name": null,
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "DocumentId": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Applicant Sign Here",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }],
                "initialHereTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": null,
                    "xPosition": null,
                    "width": "100",
                    "TabLabel": null,
                    "tabid": null,
                    "ScaleValue": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "RequireAll": "FALSE",
                    "RecipientId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "optional": "false",
                    "Name": null,
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Applicant Initial Here",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }],
                "dateSignedTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": null,
                    "xPosition": null,
                    "width": "100",
                    "TabLabel": null,
                    "tabid": null,
                    "ScaleValue": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "RecipientId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "Name": null,
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "DocumentId": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Applicant Date Signed",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }]
            },
            "routingOrder": null,
            "rolename": null,
            "recipientId": "1",
            "name": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "email": "xyz@gcps.com",
            "clientUserId": "1000"
        }, {
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": null,
                    "xPosition": null,
                    "width": "100",
                    "TabLabel": null,
                    "tabid": null,
                    "ScaleValue": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "RecipientId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "optional": "false",
                    "Name": null,
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "DocumentId": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Guarantor SignHere",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }],
                "initialHereTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": null,
                    "xPosition": null,
                    "width": "100",
                    "TabLabel": null,
                    "tabid": null,
                    "ScaleValue": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "RequireAll": "FALSE",
                    "RecipientId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "optional": "false",
                    "Name": null,
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Guarantor Initial Here",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }],
                "dateSignedTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": null,
                    "xPosition": null,
                    "width": "100",
                    "TabLabel": null,
                    "tabid": null,
                    "ScaleValue": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "RecipientId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "Name": null,
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "DocumentId": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Guarantor Date Signed",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }]
            },
            "routingOrder": null,
            "rolename": null,
            "recipientId": "2",
            "name": "XXXXXXXXXTestcase",
            "email": "yyy@gcps.com",
            "clientUserId": "2000"
        }],
        "carbonCopies": [{
            "routingOrder": "11",
            "recipientId": "11",
            "name": "DealerFunding",
            "email": "ggggg@cccc.com"
        }, {
            "routingOrder": "12",
            "recipientId": "12",
            "name": "CURRENt_DSR",
            "email": "tttt@hkhhk.com"
        }, {
            "routingOrder": "13",
            "recipientId": "13",
            "name": "DSR_TEAM_LEAD",
            "email": "JohnDoe@gcpa.com"
        }]
    },
    "messagelock": "false",
    "emailsubject": "Test Subject",
    "emailblurb": "Test Message",
    "documents": [{
        "name": "CodeOfConduct.pdf",
        "documentid": "1",
        "documentBase64": null
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying **Signer.ClientUserId** which indicates that signer is an [embedded recipient](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning). Email will be sent to the Signer if you create the envelope without the ClientUserId parameter.

For embedded signing, after envelope creation, your application will have to make a call to [EnvelopeViews:CreateRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) and generate the signing URL.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am making call to EnvelopeViews:CreateRecipient but my endpoint is 'endpoint/envelopeId/views/sender'. IS that right? Or should it be ''endpoint/envelopeId/views/recipient'? I will really appreciate your quick response. We need to open the DocuSign URL in our application and the authorized person to see the sender's view with all the recipients embedded, So we are using 'views/sender'.

Comment: To add to above we are using EnvelopeViews: createSender.

Comment: You are getting confused between [embedded sending](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSending) and [embedded signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning). Read the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) I have provided in my answer. In your case if you remove the **clientUserId** parameter, in your envelope creation request, emails will be sent to recipients.

Comment: Thanks @CodingDawg, after removing the ClientUserId from Envelope creation I can send email.